# How to get System volume information on all windows OS

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I am looking to retrieve the system volume information on all the flavors of windows OS,
but not able to find a unique way to do this. As per my investigation.

waveOutGetVolume() :- will work till windows XP only
IAudioEndPoint, :- will work only in VISTA and above OS

Please help me to get some common solution to get system volume information.